# Referencing a field in my expression

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference, field

When I run my code, the program cannot find the reference to my field. How can I fix this?
The field that has no reference is **"Me![SetupMenuID]."**

```
    Dim con As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim stSql As String

On Error GoTo SetupButtonClick_Err

    ' Find the item in the Switchboard Items table
    ' that corresponds to the button that was clicked.
    Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    stSql = "SELECT * FROM [Setup Sheet Items] "
    stSql = stSql & "WHERE [SetupMenuID]=" & Me![SetupMenuID] & " AND [SetupItemNumber]=" & numBtn
    rs.Open stSql, con, 1   ' 1 = adOpenKeyset
```

Comment: Do you have a control on your form named `SetupMenuID`?

Comment: @braX It is not a control on the form, but a field on one of my tables.

Comment: Then try `Me.SetupMenuID`

Comment: Something is very wrong here. If `[SetupMenuID]` is a column on one of your tables then it should not be setup like an outside variable in your SQL string. (Assuming your table is literally called `Me`) Then the line should be `stSql = stSql & "WHERE [SetupMenuID] = Me![SetupMenuID] AND [SetupItemNumber]=" & numBtn`. However, there would need to be some sort of `JOIN` involved in that, which is information we are missing at the moment.

Comment: `Me` refers to a form, not a table. That's why it's not working.

Comment: The field must be in the form's RecordSource.

Comment: I found the problem. `Me![SetupMenuID]` was originally defined as a variable on an SQL statement. But the form was linked to the wrong table. I corrected this by going to the property sheet of the form. I went under Data and then changed the Record Source to the right table. Now it works again.